# android: show notification under certain conditions

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

I have searched information under this topic for a while.  I think what I want to do is common.  I'm creating a word learning app.  I want to show a piece of notification in the notification center when there are some words should be reviewed.  It's not based on the time.  What I want is:

```
if (isNeedReview()) {
    show notification
}
```

I think I need the AlarmManager, but it's based on time.  Anybody know how to handle this?  What need I look up? Any advice will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you have to display notifications even if the app is not in the foreground ?

Comment: @Skaard-Solo yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

You would first use an AlarmManager to start your Service on a set schedule (say every half hour). Your Service would then perform the logic necessary to check if a word needs a review and show a notification as appropriate.

A basic service that performs this functionality would look something like this:

```
public class ReviewCheckService extends IntentService {
    public ReviewCheckService() {}

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (isNeedReview()) {
            showNotification();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, I will do some research on what you said.